# Swift. Создание интерфейсов через классы

Tags: swift, классы, ui

Учусь разработке приложений на свифт. В этой области новичок.
Делаю приложение - органайзер. Хочу сделать чтобы для каждого дня недели был один класс, фактически шаблон.
Как реализовать подобное?
(Какого-то кода нет, все попытки не удались)

Comment: Всмысле "Какого-то кода нет, все попытки не удались"? Это как, у Вас среда разработки выключилась или кто-то стер Ваши попытки? Вы же представляете себе как должен выглядеть ваш код (хоть чучуть) и уже пробовали что-то писать. Так и пробуйте это сделать. Если с чем то конкретным проблема - тогда опишите что не работает в Вашем коде. Или что работает, но не так как хотелось бы. А так получается что весь Ваш вопрос можно расценить как ТЗ которое Вы сами не пытались решить. А решили на авось - может кто и напишет код готовый, только подписать апку придумать иконку и на публикацию в аппсторе.

Comment: Это значит что моих знаний не хватает для того чтобы сделать что-то похожее на то, что я описал выше. 
Я прошу не написать за меня приложение, а объяснить как это работает в swiftUI. 
@V.March

Comment: Попробуйте сделать структуру с  днями и метод в котором будет приниматся параметр день. Как то так.

Comment: @ГеоргийКруглов начните с того, что составьте для себя описание приложения - что оно должно делать, как оно должно выглядеть, нарисуйте на бумаге или где-то еще экраны, что и как на них должно выводиться, и начинайте писать самостоятельно, решая отдельные задачи (например как вывести список, показать новый экран и тд) здесь задаются конкретные вопросы, если что-то не получается, возможно что первый вариант стоит сделать на обычном Swift, а не на SwiftUI, так как последний при кажущейся простоте может содержать немало подводных камней, на данный момент ему не хватает гибкости

Comment: @ГеоргийКруглов То, что Вы указали, что пишете приложение - это уже знак что вы что-то да написали. А уж если задумались о том, как сделать шаблон который подходит для всех дней недели, значит уже как минимум написали реализацию для одного дня. Но, смею предположить что у Вас уже имеется код на каждый из 7-ми дней. Предположил  это потому, что желание вынести повторяющийся (шаблонный код) в какой-то отдельный клас возникает когда уже замахался копипастить одно и то-же, и понимаешь что если 2-3 раза скопипастил - на это еще можно закрыть глаза. Но 7 - это уже ни в 
какой СОЛИД не лезет.